# SAS: Remove observations from data set if they match an observation in another data set

Tags: sas

I'm just learning SAS. This is a pretty simple question -- I'm probably overthinking it.

I have a data set called `people_info` and one of the variables is `SocialSecurityNum`. I have another table called `invalid_ssn` with a single variable: unique and invalid `SocialSecurityNum` observations.

I would like to have a DATA step (or PROC SQL step) that outputs to `invalid_people_info` if the `SocialSecurityNum` of the person (observation) matches one of the values in the `invalid_ssn` table. Otherwise, it will output back to `people_info`.

What's the best way to do this?

**Edit: More info, to clarify...**

`people_info` looks like this:

```
name     SocialSecurityNum
joe      123
john     456
mary     876
bob      657
```

`invalid_ssn` looks like this:

```
SocialSecurityNum
456
876
```

What I want is for `people_info` to change (in place) and look like this:

```
name     SocialSecurityNum
joe      123
bob      657
```

and a new table, called `invalid_people_info` to look like this:

```
name     SocialSecurityNum
john     456
mary     876
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement isn't clear. Do you want to remove all the invalid SSNs from `people_info` and put them into a new dataset? If so, this should work. You'll have to sort your datasets by SocialSecurityNum first.

```
data people_info invalid_people_info;
    merge people_info (in=a) invalid_ssn (in=b);
    by SocialSecurityNum;
    if b then output invalid_people_info;
    else output people_info;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was hung up on the merge with what I was thinking of as the 'reference' table.

Answer (score 5):

The data step shown by Hong Ooi is great, but youou could also do this with proc sql without the need to sort first and also without actually doing a full merge.

```
proc sql noprint;

   create table invalid_people_info as
   select *
   from people_info
   where socialsecuritynum in (select distinct socialsecuritynum from invalid_ssn)
   ;

   create table people_info as
   select *
   from people_info
   where socialsecuritynum not in (select distinct socialsecuritynum from invalid_ssn)
   ;

quit;
```

This simply selects all rows where ssn is (not) in the distinct list of invalid ssn's.

Comment: What if the 'key' is represented by more than one variable, e.g. 'socialsecuritynum' , 'birthdate', and 'nationality' ?

Comment: Mmh that would work but it doesn't look very efficient/robust....imagine that with numeric identifiers you have to pull some trick like 
C = A*1000+B  , if A is a  three figures identifier - and this kind of stuff seems prone to human errors. And with strings it would consume a lot of time. I was hoping in something like " where a & b & c  not in ..." (which is wrong btw). Any idea?

Comment: you can put an and in between each where statement with a separate sub query, this may take just as long as concatenating depending on how sas handles subqueries.