# SAS Split / Merge file into two separate files

Tags: merge, sas, subset

I have 2 files a master file ("master") and a list of IDs ("list"). I would like to split the master file into two subsets : A - which contains observations having the IDs in the file "list" and B - which contains observations not having the IDs not in the file "list".
For example :

```
MASTER:
ID     Colour
1      Red
2      Yellow
3      Blue
4      Green
5      Purple
6      Orange
7      Black
8      White

LIST:
ID
1
2
3
```

Therefore,

```
A:
ID     Colour
1      Red
2      Yellow
3      Blue

B:
ID     Colour
4      Green
5      Purple
6      Orange
7      Black
8      White
```

Thus I will end up with Number obs in A + Number obs in B = Number obs in "master"

What `if` conditions must I put in the file below to achieve this ? (The example is very simple, in reality I have over 70 thousand unique IDs)

```
data A;
merge master (in=a) list (in=b);
if a=? and b=?;
by ID;
run;

data b;
merge master (in=a) list (in=b);
if a=? and b=?;
by ID;
run;
```

Comment: I think this answers my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645678/sas-remove-observations-from-data-set-if-they-match-an-observation-in-another-d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data in_list not_in_list;
 merge master (in=a) 
       list   (in=b)
       ;
 by ID;
 if b then output in_list;
 else output not_in_list;
run;
```

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just code with no explanation. Please improve your answer by explaining what your code does and how it answers the question. Please read [this advice on answering programming questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).